# Updatable Label text according to combobox filled with an Acces database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hi I'm using Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition, so I have a combobox that gets filled with items from a data base made with Microsoft Acces, the combobox is filled with the values stored in a column from a table in de database so the user can select an "option" from it, I want to add labels that show the values for the corresponding row of that column. I used the Data Source panel to drag and drop the labels corresponding to the values that I want and it works it show the value that I want when I compile the application (at least I think it does, it could be that it's only selecting the first entry) the problem is that when I select a diferent entry on the combobox the labels don't refresh with the new values. How can I do that?

*edit*

Ok soo I guess my real question is how does Visual Basic Populates de combobox and gets the value of the other Acces DB entrys to change the .text value of the labels? And I mean the actual code that does that.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this helps at all](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/excel-l/dynamic-excel-forms-using-vba-1037672#M1101469)

Comment: Not really but thank you. I want the text on the label to change dynamically since the DB im using is really big creating a label for each one and making it visile depending on the option of the combobox would be impractical.

Comment: That's not what a `label` is meant for though. I would create a dashbooard-like page. Have a drop-down/combo box, and on submission have logic serve up the correct form/page.

Comment: What is the point of a link to Dynamic Excel Forms using VBA? Perhaps you would care to explain before I vote down?

Comment: Its not linked to a Dynamic Excel Form is linked to an Acces database and its not ment for the user to modify the values of the data base just to browse them and see the contents of each entry of the datbase via labels

Comment: @FelixArturoMaciasIbarra I am not sure if you are talking to me or to Ryan, I was talking to Ryan. I do not believe the link posted is relevant to your question.

Comment: Felix, Remou was directing the comment towards me. @Remou That link shows how to do that within excel using VBA. If you understand what the code does, you can use it as a starting point. A vote down is a bit harsh but to his their own. [edit I must have been commenting at the same time as Remou]

Comment: I am sorry, but first, answers that are just links are discouraged in SO, second, I do not see how VBA and Excel are a suitable answer for VB.Net and Access.

Answer (score 0):

Put some code in the on_click event of the combo box to change the label captions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, apereantly Visual Creates new data sources each time you drag and drop an item from the Data Sources Panel so all you have to do is make sure that VB is using the same data source used in the combo boxes and the labels so they will update automatically when you choose an option from the combo box, I did it by finding the proper elements in the *Form1.Designer.vb* file of my project and editing 'DataBindings.Add' property of the labels.